# Pre & post, but different n at each grade level. What type of ANOVA should I use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I conducted pre- and post- tests (each graded with a quantitative score) among three different grade levels in a middle school where each grade level had a *different* number of students (23, 20, and 21 respectively).

- What type of ANOVA test should I use??

  My first thought was to use an "ANOVA: Two-Factor with Replication", but it cannot be completed without equal sample sizes. I also thought about running two separate One-Way ANOVAs and subsequent Post Hoc tests, but that would give me too small of an alpha because of so many tests. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Not sure what software you are using, but an ANOVA with a between-subjects factor and a within-subjects factor will work and does not require balanced cell sizes (equal sample sizes).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you did, you have three factors and no replication:

- Grade level: Fixed effects factor with 3 levels.
- Student: Random effects factor with an unbalanced number of levels, nested within grade level factor.
- Pre/post: Fixed effects factor with 2 levels, crossed with student and grade level.